# Proper usage of OnClickListener Android

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-tabs

I am new to Android Development and I am trying a simple program with Tabs..

MainActivity.java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    if(id == R.id.search)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You tapped on SEARCH !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter your Name"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et1"
    android:hint="Enter your ID"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et2"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When is run this app, the app instantly crashes before loading.

This started when I added the 'OnClickListener' code in the 'onCreate' method.

Please help me. What am I missing?

Comment: Post  your logcat id app crashes

Comment: @Apurva The logs are updated in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chintan Soni is correct. Your problem is caused by the declaration of your b1 Button in the main activity class. This button is in the "fragment_main" layout file which is instantiated by your Fragment.

If you move your code to the onCreateView of your PlaceholderFragment so that it looks like the below code the app will run.

Note that I have changed getApplicationContext() to getActivity() also.

```
        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        Button b1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
```

To show a different view for each tab you need to declare an different Fragment for each one e.g. FragmentOne, FragmentTwo, FragmentThree each with their own onCreatView method to show a seperate layout file. Then in the getView method of your SectionsPagerAdapter implement the following code to show each Fragment according to the ViewPagers position.

```
      @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new FragmentOne();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new FragmentTwo();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new FragmentThree();
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }
```

Comment: Ok ! Thanks :)  Why did you change getApplicationContext() to getActivity(). will you please explain
?

Comment: It's not a method available to Fragment :)

Comment: Now, there are 3 tabs in my App. And all the Tabs show the two EditTexts and Button. I want that to be shown in only 1 tab !! what is the problem ???

Comment: Your SectionsPagerAdapter getView method is the part which adds fragments to your ViewPager. In this method you have the line  return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1); This instantiates the same Fragment three times. If you want to have a different Fragment for each tab you need to do a switch on "position" and return different Fragments according to the cases 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Yes, but to add that Fragment to only 1 tab, what should i do? @Ivan

Comment: 3 Tabs. Each having a different XML Stucture.

Comment: Edited my answer to explain

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working. I'll text you if i have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got you... :)
I will explain your problem.
You have put button's find view by id inside your activity's `onCreate()`. But Your button lies inside your fragment's layout file. So you would not find it in your activity xml file.

**Solution:** 
put below code in your `onCreateView()`:

```
Button b1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // your onclick code goes here
        }
    });
```

Inshort, keep everything as it is. Just change your `onCreateView()` to the one shown below:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        Button b1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // your onclick code goes here
            }
       });
        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: I put the code. The 'view' in the first line got replaced with 'mViewPager'. And still no success.

Comment: @AdhishThite you need to find the view from `rootView`, not in `mViewPager`. Its the fragment that holds your inflated views, not `ViewPager`. `ViewPager` just gave you the functionalites like you can paginate any collection you give to it.